# ie SendQuery bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have form with jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var type_service_operator;
    var param_for_form = "<?php echo $param_for_form;?>";

        function ShowPopUp() {

            var type_service = "<?php echo $type;?>";
            var type_service_serv = "<?php echo $type_service_serv;?>";         
            var pseudo = new Array();
            var sms = new Array();
            var podpiska = new Array();

            if (type_service_serv == 'pseudo'){

                $('.pop-inner').empty();

pseudo.push("<a href='#' class='button2' onclick='SendQuery();'>продолжить</a>");
```

`IE` loads the button but does not send:

`<a href="#" class="button2" onclick="SendQuery();">subscribe</a>`

How can I get this to work in IE?  Other browsers?

Comment: in other browsers does it work ?? . and where do you want to send the button

Comment: use ie developer toolbar to find what's not initializing